# Como acceder a objet de javascript

Tags: javascript, object

Hola tengo este codigo javascript:

```js
require("TimeSlice").guard(function() {
    (require("ServerJSDefine")).handleDefines([["cr:692209", ["cancelIdleCallbackBlue"], {
        "__rc": ["cancelIdleCallbackBlue", null]
    }
    , 3419], ["DTSGInitData", [], {
        "token": "987654321", "async_get_token": "123456789"
    }
}

 ]
 ]
 )
)
```

quisiera acceder a el valor de **async_get_token** osea 123456789
alguna idea de como lograr esto ?

He intentado esto

```
console.log(array[2].async_get_token);
```

Answer (score 1):

Como tu fuente es un *arreglo*, sólo debes obtener la propiedad dentro del item de dicho arreglo; ten en cuenta que los items de los arreglos **comienzan con la posición 0**, por lo que si se aplica a tu código el valor se obtiene así

```js
function obtener(){
  var data = ["DTSGInitData", [], { "token": "987654321", "async_get_token": "123456789" }, 3515];
  alert(data[2].async_get_token);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="obtener()">Obtener valor</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: lo que pasa es que yo tengo una funcion: `require("TimeSlice").guard(function() {
    (require("ServerJSDefine")).handleDefines([["cr:692209", ["cancelIdleCallbackBlue"], {
        "__rc": ["cancelIdleCallbackBlue", null]
    }
    , 3419], ["DTSGInitData", [], {
        "token": "987654321", "async_get_token": "123456789"
    }
}

 ]
 ]
 )
)`

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes lograr de este modo:

```
let datos = ["DTSGInitData", [], {
    "token": "987654321", "async_get_token": "123456789"
}
, 3515]

console.log(datos[2]["async_get_token"])
```

**EXPLICACIÓN**

- Dentro de tu array principal, el objeto que deseas leer esta en la posición 2, entonces indicas que la variable acceda a la posición 2 y luego a la clave "async_get_token"

Comment: lo que pasa es que yo tengo una funcion: `require("TimeSlice").guard(function() {
    (require("ServerJSDefine")).handleDefines([["cr:692209", ["cancelIdleCallbackBlue"], {
        "__rc": ["cancelIdleCallbackBlue", null]
    }
    , 3419], ["DTSGInitData", [], {
        "token": "987654321", "async_get_token": "123456789"
    }
}

 ]
 ]
 )
)`